# Assign and access variable value from another module in Python

Tags: python, variables, module, assign

I have two modules "main" and "utils". In "utils" I have 2 variables to be global "cod_user" and "name_user". In the "main" module I imported the 2 variables, it has two classes "A" and "B".
In class "A" I need to assign value to "cod_user" and "name_user" from the utils module and in class "B" I need to retrieve the value assigned by class "A", but when I access the value it is empty.

My code

```
utils.py #MODULE

cod_user = ...
name_user = ...
```

```
main.py #MODULE

from util import cod_user, name_user

class A():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.assign_values(1, 'User test')
        

    def assign_values(self, cod, name):
        #SET VALUES
        cod_user = cod
        name_user = name
        print(cod_user, name_user)



class B():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.get_values()

    def get_values(self):
        #GET VALUES
        cod = cod_user  
        name = name_user
        print(cod, name) #ERROR VALUES EMPTY


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ca = A()
    cb = B()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired functionality by defining the variables in a separate class to hold the shared data. Here is an example

```
class Utils:
    cod_user = None
    name_user = None
```

Import the util module in another class and use the variables like:

```
from util import Utils
class A():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.assign_values(1, 'User test')
        

    def assign_values(self, cod, name):
        #SET VALUES
        Utils.cod_user = cod # changes here
        Utils.name_user = name # changes here
        print(Utils.cod_user, Utils.name_user)
```

You can apply the same logic in other classes.
You can also use the global keyword to access the global variables locally. But, using global variables can make it more difficult to manage and track changes to the variable's value, especially in larger programs with multiple modules and classes

Comment: Hi 'Dejene T.', This solution also worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

The assign_values method of class A, which assigns values to the global variables cod_user and name_user, is where the problem resides. Instead of changing the global variables from the utils module, the assignment statements cod_user = cod and name_user = name create new local variables.

This may be fixed by using the global keyword in the assign_values method to clearly state that you wish to change the global variables.

**utils.py**

```py
cod_user = None
name_user = None
```

**main.py**

```py
from utils import cod_user, name_user

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.assign_values(1, 'User test')

    def assign_values(self, cod, name):
        global cod_user, name_user  # Declare variables as global
        cod_user = cod  # Assign value to global variable
        name_user = name  # Assign value to global variable
        print(cod_user, name_user)

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_values()

    def get_values(self):
        cod = cod_user
        name = name_user
        print(cod, name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ca = A()
    cb = B()
```

The assign_values method adds the variables global cod_user and name_user to make it clear that they should be updated. This prevents the values assigned in class A from being empty when retrieved in class B.

**Please tell me if it worked for you!**

Comment: Hello 'Karo', I did the test here and it worked correctly. Thanks for the help.